# dataURL(file/image/pdf anything) into base64 ionic 2

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic2, ionic3

i want to convert any dataurl(file/image/pdf anything) in to base 64 
this my ts file function which is open any file and get the file url

```
 fnOpenFile(){

   this.fileChooser.open()
  .then(uri =>{
   console.log(uri);
  }

  )
  .catch(e =>{
   console.log(e);
   }
   );
  }
```

this is my html file

```
<button ion-button secondary (click)='fnOpenFile()'>Choose File</button>
```

i open file successfully but now i want to convert thi file in to base64

Comment: See [this native plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/base64/)

Comment: @devqon i use this plugin but get null when we convert to base64.i get this type of path when choose file file:///storage/emulated/0/myfile.doc

Answer (score 1):

This plugin converts to base64,
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/base64/